# For all $a,b,n \in \mathbb N$, $0 \leq n(a+b+1)-n^2 +b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, proof-explanation, natural-numbers

I claim the following:

> For all $a,b,n \in \mathbb N$, we have that $0 \leq n(a+b+1)-n^2 +b$.

This seems true for me... Although how do I really check if this is true? I was thinking about doing it by induction, but the fact that we have to deal with three variables is confusing me. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untrue. For $a=b=1$ and $n=100,$ we get
$$n(a+b+1)-n^2+b=100(1+1+1)-100^2+1=-9699.$$

General advice: higher order terms dominate.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful! But I have another question, how can I determine the least $n$ in which this fails?

Comment: @AirMike It starts to fail at $n=4,$ assuming your natural numbers do not include $0.$ Work with $n=1,2,3$ manually and separately show that it always holds in these cases. Then find a counterexample for $n=4.$

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!